# Proving a correspondence is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, vectors

I've been trying to get my head around this for a bit but I am not sure where to start. Here is the question:

Prove the following theorem:

Let $Y$ be a closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that  $0 \in Y$ and $ Y \cap \mathbb{R}^n_{+} = \{0\}$. For each $i = 1, 2.... n$ define a correspondence $Y_i:\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \mapsto  \mathbb{R}^n$ as:
$$
Y_i(z) = \{y \in Y: y_{-i} = z \}
$$

Then for each $ i = 1, 2, ... n$ and each $ z \in R^{n-1}$, the set $Y_i(z)$ is closed and there exists $ M \in  \mathbb{R}$  such that for all  $y \in Y_i(z)$, $y_i < M$

I am kinda struggling to see why the correspondence $Y_i(z)$ would be closed.

I've tried this approach:

Assume $Y_i(z)$ isn't closed

Then there exists ${y_n} \in Y_i(z)$ such that $y_n \mapsto y'$ and $y' \notin Y_i(z)$. But we know $y' \in Y$. And I honestly don't know where to go from here. Any help or clue would be great. I am trying to learn how to get comfortable with real analysis and related problems more, so any thoughts on how to even think about this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at an answer. It isn't fully formalized and I am not sure if I am correct.

If $Y_i(z)$ is closed for a particular $z$ and $i$ then we know a couple of things:

$\exists \ \{\hat{y}_k\} \in Y_i(z)$

such that

$ \hat{y}_k \rightarrow \hat{y} $

where $\hat{y} \in Y_i(z)$

It's also the case that all of these variables exist in $Y$

It also has to be that $\hat{y}_{-ik} = z$. That's how it got selected in $Y_i(z)$

For the entire sequence all the elements of each vector except the $i^{th}$ element are constantly just $z$.

So the only element we actually have to check for convergence is the $i^{th}$ element.

Let $\hat{y}_{ik} \rightarrow y^*_i$ and $y^*_i \in y^*$

Let $y^*_{-i} = z$. This is so the whole vector $y^*$ is the limit of $\hat{y}_k$.

Since  $y^*_{-i} = z$ we know $y^* \in Y_i(z)$. Therefore the limit of the sequence {\hat{y}_k } exists within $Y_i(z)$. This is for any arbitrary $i$ and $z$. Therefore
$Y_i(z)$ is closed for all $i$ and $z$.

For the second bit, I believe it's trivial from here:

$y_{ik} \rightarrow y^*_i$, which means that $ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall n \in N \ d(y^*_i, y_{ik}) < \epsilon$.

That means we can find a big enough $\epsilon$ such that $N = 0$. That is, the whole sequence is less than $\epsilon$ distance away from $y^*_i$. Therefore there will exist some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_ik < M$ for all $k$.